# Select Random yet distinct rows from table - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with various categories, and multiple entries for each category.

```
Word    |  Category  
------------------  
Apple   |  Food  
Orange  |  Food  
Grapes  |  Food  
Mango   |  Food
```

I wish to retrieve 3 random rows for the category 'food', for which I run the following query,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category='food' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3"

$fetch_row = mysqli_query($db_connect, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_row)) {
            array_push($words, $row['word']);
        }
```

However, when I print the contents of the array $words, they tend to repeat sometimes (not on all runs), for example;

> Apple, Orange, Apple

i.e. Its not always unique. I want to select random, yet unique words for a given category. What am I doing wrong? I've tried going through other related answers, but I keep messing something up. I've also tried the following query;

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category='food' GROUP BY category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

But this still gives repetitions occasionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `word` column have same values, do `GROUP BY word` like below:-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category='food' GROUP BY word LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say, except to wonder how I missed this bit. Thanks for pointing it out x)

Comment: @Anas  we all learn from mistakes. Don't worry. glad to help you :):)